# Using Traefik as an ingress controller for minikube

Tags: minikube, traefik

I am looking at traefik for an ingress controller for my minikube cluster.  I have tried to follow the instructions provide in Traefik but my service External-IP is stuck in  state indefinitely.  Can anyone recommend a command that might explain why my service is failing to get an external-ip.  `kubectl describe svc traefik` fails to provide any information.  I have the latest minikube installed on MacOS with NO addons installed.

I also have the latest version of Helm installed. And executed the command

`helm install --name ingress  --namespace kube-system --set dashboard.enabled=true stable/traefik`

I have successfully install nginx as an ingress controller.

Comment: Could you share your configuration files?

Comment: If you used the files referenced in the Traefik kubernetes guide, they currently have a few shortcomings. https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/1735 is dealing with that right now.

Comment: I'm current trying to use Helm. `helm install --name ingress  --namespace kube-system --set dashboard.enabled=true stable/traefik`

Comment: Did anything happen here @TimoReimann ?

Comment: @vonGohren the PR I referenced has been merged by now. Due to technical limitations though, it's not reflected on the traefik.io page yet. For the specific problem at hand, it'd be helpful to see the DEBUG level logs.

Comment: @TimoReimann The Traefik user guide for k8s seems updated for the PR you mentioned. I have the same problem  when using helm to install traefik on my minikube.  If I  deploy traefik using Deployment, everything works fine until I access `traefik-ui.minikube` keeps telling me that timeout when connecting to port 80..
BTW I try to set log level to DEBUG..it's very hard to trace any useful information...